# Correct way for writing multiple custom Jackson deserializers to handle inheritance

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize a quite complicated set of JSON documents with Jackson. To handle inheritance I implemented some custom deserializers.

To choose the correkt class I have to check the properties of the next node. Therefore I read the tree, check the properties and choose the correct class.

After that I read the JSON via `mapper.readerFor(targetClass).readValue(rootNode)`. Everything is fine until here.

But as I use `mapper.readerFor(...)` the next called serializer gets an `ObjectReader` instance instead of an `ObjectMapper`. But I need an `ObjectMapper` instance.

How could I do it better?

Here is one of my deserializers, which cause my problem:

```java
public AbstractParametersObject deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    Class<? extends AbstractParametersObject> targetClass = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
    ObjectNode root =mapper.readTree(p);
    boolean isReference = root.has("$ref");
    boolean isParameter = root.has("in");

    if (isReference) targetClass = ParameterAsReference.class;
    else if (isParameter) {
        targetClass = Optional.of(root.get("in")).map(JsonNode::asText).map(value -> {
            Class<? extends AbstractParametersObject> effectiveClass = null;

            switch (value) {
                case "body": effectiveClass = BodyParameterObject.class;
                    break;
                case "query": effectiveClass = QueryParameterObject.class;
                    break;
                case "path": effectiveClass = PathParameterObject.class;
                    break;
                case "formData": effectiveClass = FormDataParameterObject.class;
                    break;
                case "header": effectiveClass = HeaderParameterObject.class;
                    break;
            }

            return effectiveClass;
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("todo"));
    }

    AbstractParametersObject parametersObject = mapper.readerFor(targetClass)
                                                      .readValue(root);
    return parametersObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was quite simple. Instead calling `mapper.readerFor(targetClass).readValue(root)` to deserialize the node tree into an object I had to call `mapper.treeToValue(root, targetClass)`.

Here is the working version of the method I posted in my question:

```java
public AbstractParametersObject deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
    throws IOException {

    Class<? extends AbstractParametersObject> targetClass = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
    ObjectNode root =mapper.readTree(p);
    boolean isReference = root.has("$ref");
    boolean isParameter = root.has("in");

    if (isReference) targetClass = ParameterAsReference.class;
    } else if (isParameter) {
        targetClass = Optional.of(root.get("in")).map(JsonNode::asText).map(value -> {
            Class<? extends AbstractParametersObject> effectiveClass = null;

            switch (value) {
                case "body": effectiveClass = BodyParameterObject.class;
                    break;
                case "query": effectiveClass = QueryParameterObject.class;
                    break;
                case "path": effectiveClass = PathParameterObject.class;
                    break;
                case "formData": effectiveClass = FormDataParameterObject.class;
                    break;
                case "header": effectiveClass = HeaderParameterObject.class;
                    break;
            }

            return effectiveClass;
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("todo"));
    }

    return mapper.treeToValue(root, targetClass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be easier than you think, although I can't tell for sure without seeing some of your JSON examples.  Jackson can deal with polymorphism directly without custom serializers using the @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes annotations, so long as there is a field with a value indicating which subclass to create.  For example, suppose I have two different documents that share some common fields:

```
{ "type":"square", "name":"my square", "x":12, "y":34, "size":22 }
{ "type":"rectangle", "name":"my rect", "x":9, "y":11, "width":4, "height":9 }
```

This could be annotated with:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
    @Type(name = "square", value = Square.class),
    @Type(name = "rectangle", value = Rectangle.class)
})
public abstract class Shape {
   public String name;
   public int x;
   public int y;
}
public class Square extends Shape {
   public int size;
}
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
   public int width;
   public int height;
}
```

Comment: You answer works but isn't the way to go for me for two reasons. First reason is that I can't modify the JSON value. They must match their schema (JSON Schema). Second reason is that I can only determine the target class if I check the root node for specific fields and their values. I gave you a upvote.

Comment: Hmmm, I see you do not have a single field value to discriminate, you have to combine the "$ref" and "in" fields.